# How to learn a neural network with equivalent constraints on the weights

Tags: neural-networks, architecture

Let $f(x)$ be an output of a neural network with input $x$.

My data is a pair $(x,y)$ and my loss function is a function of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, i.e., $g(f(x),f(y))$.

What kind of architecture enables this learning?
I could make two copies of the same neural network, but can the weights be coordinated in the back propagation?

Comment: Can you please put your **specific** question in the title? "Duplicating a neural network" is _not_ a question and it's _not_ specific.

Comment: A similar question has been answered at https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/34320/32722 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/49875127/3731823. You don't make a copy of the network, there is just one but it is used for separate inputs.